# MFC: how to draw text with wrapping and v-centering?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

The following code draws text using DrawText (single line) and DrawTextEx (wrapping). I want both v-centered.

```
    CRect rect1(50, 50, 100, 125);
    CRect rect2(100, 50, 500, 125);

    CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 0, RGB(192, 192, 192));

    pDC->MoveTo(rect1.left, rect1.top);
    pDC->LineTo(rect2.right, rect2.top);
    pDC->MoveTo(rect1.left, rect1.bottom);
    pDC->LineTo(rect2.right, rect2.bottom);

    pDC->DrawText("hello", rect1, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
    pDC->DrawTextEx("0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 ",
                    rect2, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER, NULL);
```

The output is figure below, looks like single line is v-centered but not the one with wrapping. Also, note that some of the upper line is covered, which should be addressed as well.

[image]

Comment: Documentation for  [DT_VCENTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) states: "Centers text vertically. This value is used only with the DT_SINGLELINE value."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DT_VCENTER` can only be used in combination with `DT_SINGLELINE`. For multi-line drawing, use `DT_CALCRECT` to obtain the height, then manually calculate the center. Example:

```
CString str = "0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789";
CRect rc = rect2;
dc.DrawText(str, &rc, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_LEFT | DT_CALCRECT);
rc.OffsetRect(0, (rect2.Height() - rc.Height()) / 2);
dc.DrawText(str, &rc, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_LEFT);
```